# How to get sql dump for a oracle sql query from Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I am writing an sql query in Oracle 12c Database which is returning around 500K records. I need to take dump or export it in a readable format in a faster way.

I am connecting using Oracle Sql Developer for running the query.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: @Littlefoot has answered the "how".  I'd question the "why".  Specifically, because you say "export it in a _readable_ format"  No one is going to read a half-million line report.  If you plan on consuming the data by some other process, then explain what that process is so that we can recommend an _optimal_ solution and not just your pre-conceived soltuion.  Beware of asking an 'x-y question'.   - https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: If you want a dmp file, use data pump. If you want faster data exports from SQLDev, I have tips on that.

Answer (score 0):

"Faster" than what?

---

The simplest way is to right-click the result, choose "Export" from the menu, set preferences and *export* data.

Or, switch to PL/SQL, use `UTL_FILE` package and create file in a directory on the database server; that's pretty fast.

Or, spool the result into a CSV file. SQL Developer can do that, SQL*Plus as well. Investigate usage of `SET` commands which let you decide what you want to do. Make sure NOT to display query output on the screen as it'll take time to display half a million rows.